# How can I upgrade RPM version 4.4.* to RPM version 4.8.*?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

I am getting error below when I am trying to install a package on CentOS 5. After some research it seems like my RPM version needs to be upgraded; How can I upgrade RPM version 4.4.2.3 to RPM version 4.8.0?

```
#sudo rpm -ivh test.1.0.0.noarch.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by test.1.0.0.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by test.1.0.0.noarch


#rpm --version
RPM version 4.4.2.3
```

Comment: Might be easier to move to a newer CentOS distribution, CentOS 6.5, the latest, uses RPM version 4.8.0.

Comment: Is there any way to upgrade it for CentOS 5?

Comment: Why can't you rebuild the package to work on the older distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By upgrading to a newer distribution. RPM is a core part of Fedora/Red Hat/CentOS and upgrading it is close to impossible in my experience. It should not be attempted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely is that your rpm was built on an CentOS 6 machine and it cannot be install on CentOS 5. You are seeing the exact message as shown by the Red Hat website solutions page titled "RPM Compatibility from Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6 to RHEL 5 and earlier" at web address https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/41415.

Comment: These are dependencies within rpm itself. This will not help.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I have changed my answer.